# EOF blocks my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, here-document

I have this script (it is actually a snippet from a bigger script).

```
#!/bin/sh

 if [ $actualsize -ge $MAXSIZE ]; then
  read dummy FILEPOINT <<EOF
  `dd if=myfile skip=8001 count=1 bs=1|od -x`
  EOF
 fi
```

When I run it, I get

```
./bugged.sh: 9: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Apparently, the problem is the "EOF". Why does this happen and how can I achieve the same result (reading from myfile)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either stop indenting the `EOF`, or use `<<-EOF` earlier and indent it using tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Ignacio explained the error you get, but you may want to simplify your code and avoid the here document in the first place like:

```
filepoint=$(od -An -j 8001 -N 1 -t x1 < myfile)
```